# Android studio logcat error .. how to resolve the following error

Tags: android, android-logcat

How would I resolve this error?  There is no error indicated in the code

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Would really help if you post the complete logs and some of the codes that you think it is related to.

Comment: post your java file and logcat error to slove it .

Comment: Please, post your code as well as your Code.

Comment: i have posted the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 19327: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
> ```

The [`LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)` copy constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams)) was added in API level 19 and your device is running API level 18.

Note that this is just a warning in the logcat. Code requiring API level 19 was loaded by the classloader but so far there's no evidence of that being a problem.

Comment: but the log cat is not working after that ...am running this application on Samsung GT-I9300 Android 4.3,API 18...............my apps minimum sdk is 14.... how can i resolve this issue... because my app will target users form 14 to 23...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue in Android Studio and Eclipse. 
Try clean and build your application.
Or delete the R, (Don't worry, it is auto-generated)

Comment: did that.. still the same problem:(

Comment: Can you post the line of codes that has an error? hmmm. it seems that it is calling android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams instead of LinearLayout.LayoutParams. Please check your imports if it is importing android.widget.LinearLayout;

Comment: pls click on the above link in the question

Comment: What do you really want to do with your code? Since you want to support api 14, maybe you should try alternative methods since Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams; is for API 19 and above only. Try running that on Emulator / genymotion with API level 19 if error is still present.